# Store is null or not an object error in dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a function defined for the menu item "delete" on right click of any folder of the tree hierarchy, to delete a folder of tree. But on click of it I got the below error message **"Store is null or not an object error in dojo"**

Can anyone suggest me how to correct this error message?Is there something wrong in my function below?

```
<ul dojoType="dijit.Menu" id="tree_menu" style="display: none;">   
      <li dojoType="dijit.MenuItem" data-dojo-props="disabled: false,
                                     onClick: function (evt){
                                     store.deleteById(selectedItemId);
                                     resetEditor();
                                 }",>Delete project</li></ul>
```

**Tree Structure**

```
- Main Project 1 
Sub Project 1_1  
Sub Project 1_2
 * sub Project 1_3 

+ Main Project 2 - 
Main Project 3 

Sub Project 3_1 - 
Sub Project 3_2 
Sub Project 3_2_1
```

Comment: Well, you're referencing a `store` variable in that `onClick` function, but I'm guessing it's not actually available in a scope visible to that function...  Where are you actually defining your store?  (And where is `resetEditor` defined for that matter, since that may be the next thing it will complain about.)

Comment: Hi Ken, I have defined the store in the beginning of mycode.The same code works for button but fails when I convert it to a menu-item.What can be the cause?Can we implement the same code for menu-item as i have done above?As it is strange it responds to button but fails for menu-item.Here's the button code:<button id="bd" data-dojo-type="dijit.MenuItem"data-dojo-id="bd"data-dojo-props="disabled: true,onClick: function (evt){store.deleteById(selectedItemId);resetEditor();},label:'Delete project' "></button>

Answer (score 0):

it appears that the onClick function is running in the MenuItem context, which means that in your onclick function, 'this' refers to the MenuItem widget instance.

To use your store variable in the onClick method, you can first reference it in your widget like this:

```
<ul dojoType="dijit.Menu" id="tree_menu" style="display: none;">   
  <li dojoType="dijit.MenuItem" data-dojo-props="disabled: false,
                                 _store: store,
                                 onClick: function (evt){
                                 _store.deleteById(selectedItemId);
                                 resetEditor();
                             }",>Delete project</li></ul>
```

Or you can reference your global store object in the window context:

```
<ul dojoType="dijit.Menu" id="tree_menu" style="display: none;">   
  <li dojoType="dijit.MenuItem" data-dojo-props="disabled: false,
                                 onClick: function (evt){
                                 window.store.deleteById(selectedItemId);
                                 resetEditor();
                             }",>Delete project</li></ul>
```

Comment: Hi Sebastien, I tried your suggested changes in my code for the delete menuitem but it is not working.I tried both the suggested ways you have mentioned above but it is not responding for delete menuitem. I have added my entire code in the first thread under the heading "Non Working code". could you please take a look if I am doing any blunder in my code? strange part is that if we put a button instead of menuitem it works.

Comment: Hi, it seems that there is a little error in your code: in the onClick method of the MenuItem, you're calling _store.deleteById(selectedItemId); instead of this._store.deleteById(selectedItemId);

Comment: Hi Sebastien, when I used this._Store.deleteById(selectedItemId); I got this as the error message in firebug and IE dev debug tool. "'this._store' is null or not an object". My code is in the first thread under heading "Non Working code". Can you please have a look if there is something else I am missing in my code.It is one of the most weirdest issue I faced as button click calls the function but the same function isn't called from menu.My Code can be copied to a .txt and saved as.html.Open html & allow activex then it will run. right click on folder to find delete menuitem isnt working.

Comment: Hi, seems that you didn't get my explanation from yesterday: in your HTML page, replace '_store.deleteById(selectedItemId);' with 'this._store.deleteById(selectedItemId);'. _store is an attribute of your MenuItem once you set it with _store: store, so you need to use this._store into your methods to reference it.

Comment: One query Sebastien, though the code works but it creates folder only under last folder.I have added the tree pictorial structure in for look and feel in myfirst thread under tree structure heading. I mean if I right-click onSub Project 3_2_1  and click add folder it adds the folder under it  but if I do the same for other folders like Sub Project 3_2/Sub Project 3_1 it doesn't work for the clicked folder but it create folders under Sub Project 3_2_1_1 again. So can you say why is this strange behavior occurring and how can i correct it?Is something incorrect we are doing here in the code?